# Ayuda para subir una imagen a una base de datos phpmyadmin con AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, imagen

Buenos días, tengo un problema subiendo una imagen a mi base de datos. Tengo varios datos distintos y todos se guardan salvo la imagen, la cual la configuré con el nombre de columna "IMG" y tipo de archivo longblob

Este es mi HTML:

```
<div class="control-group">
              <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                <label>Fotos del platillo</label>
                <input type="file" name="IMG" class="form-control" placeholder="Fotos del platillo" id="IMG" required data-validation-required-message="Debes rellenar este espacio.">
                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Esta es la funcion de ajax dentro del mismo HTML

```
<script>        
       $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#boton2").click(function () {
          var DATE = $("#DATE").val();
          var NAME = $("#NAME").val();
          var DESCR = $("#DESCR").val();
          var IMG = $("#IMG").val();
          var COSTO = $("#COSTO").val();


          $.post("saveFitGreenMenu.php", {
            DATE: DATE,
            NAME: NAME,
            DESCR: DESCR,
            IMG: IMG,
            COSTO: COSTO
          },
          function (data, status) {
               console.log(data);
          });
        }); 
       });

    </script>
```

Esto es todo lo que tengo en el php para guardar

```
<?php
include "conexionFitGreen.php";

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }else{

$DATE = $_POST["DATE"];
$NAME = $_POST["NAME"];
$DESCR = $_POST["DESCR"];
$IMG = $_FILES["IMG"];
$COSTO = $_POST["COSTO"];


    if($con){
      //Paso 2
      $sentencia = $con->prepare("
        insert into menudia(DATE, NAME, DESCR, IMG, COSTO) 
        values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      //Paso 3
      $sentencia->bind_param("sssbi", $DATE, $NAME, $DESCR, $IMG, $COSTO);


      //Paso 4
      if($sentencia->execute()){
        //echo "Datos del paciente guardados exitosamente!";
      }

      $sentencia = $con->prepare("select * from menudia");
      if($sentencia->execute()){
        $sentencia->bind_result($DATE, $NAME, $DESCR, $IMG, $COSTO, $ID);

      }
  }
}

?>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Sé que todo está bien ya que los demás parámetros me los guarda sin problemas, pero la imagen siempre me sale en blanco en la base de datos. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Carolina, para subir archivos es un proceso diferente, ya que lo que debes de hacer es cargar el archivo a tu servidor, en la Base de Datos lo que guardas es únicamente el nombre de la imagen.

Answer (score 1):

prueba lo siguiente:

El código tiene los comentarios para que veas el proceso

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#boton2").click(function() {
    //obtine el archivo para enviar por POST:
    var IMG = document.getElementById("IMG");
    var file = IMG.files[0];

    //crea el JSON con los datos
    var datos = {
      DATE: $("#DATE").val(),
      NAME: $("#NAME").val(),
      DESCR: $("#DESCR").val(),
      COSTO: $("#COSTO").val()
    };

    //DATA sera la variable que guarde lo que envia
    //por POST con formatData()
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('img', file); //agrega el archivo(imagen)
    data.append('datos', JSON.stringify(datos)); //agrega el json con los demas datos

    //Usa $AJAX en lugar de $POST
    $.ajax({
      type: "post", //tipo de envio
      contentType: false,
      data: data, //la información que envia
      processData: false,
      async: false, //espera respuesta del servidor antes de continuar
      url: 'saveFitGreenMenu.php', //url del PHP
      success: function(response) { //si la petición fue exitosa
        alert('Registro Completo');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<?php
include "conexionFitGreen.php";

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }else{
    //obtiene los datos por POST
    $DATOS = json_decode($_POST['datos'],true);
    //separa los datos
    $DATE = $DATOS["DATE"];
    $NAME = $DATOS["NAME"];
    $DESCR = $DATOS["DESCR"];
    $COSTO = $DATOS["COSTO"];
    
    //obtiene el archivo por FILE
    $IMG = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name']; //así obtiene el archivo FILE
    $IMGNAME = $_FILES['img']['name'];     //así obtiene el nombre del archivo FILE
    $RUTA = 'mifolder/imagenes';       //aqui especifica la ruta en donde cargar la imagen

    //ASI SUBE EL ARCHIVO AL SERVIDOR
   if (!move_uploaded_file($IMG, $RUTA)) {
    $return = false;
   }

    if($con){
      //Paso 2
      $sentencia = $con->prepare("
        insert into menudia(DATE, NAME, DESCR, IMG, COSTO) 
        values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
      //Paso 3
      //$IMGNAME para guardar el nombre de la imagen nada más
      $sentencia->bind_param("sssbi", $DATE, $NAME, $DESCR, $IMGNAME, $COSTO);


      //Paso 4
      if($sentencia->execute()){
        //echo "Datos del paciente guardados exitosamente!";
      }

      $sentencia = $con->prepare("select * from menudia");
      if($sentencia->execute()){
        $sentencia->bind_result($DATE, $NAME, $DESCR, $IMGNAME, $COSTO, $ID);

      }
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

probe el código y no funcinó, de hecho ahora no guarda ninguno de los datos en la tabla, estableci la carpeta donde dice  que especifique la ruta pero ya no se cual es el problema

Comment: Código Editado* prueba de nuevo... revisa si el archivo carga realmente en la carpeta que especificaste.

Comment: Aún no funciona y no guarda el archivo tampoco donde especifico, creo que en lugar de guardar una imagen como un blob seria mejor gurdar la ruta como un varchar? aun asi no sabria como poner el codigo para que se guarde la ruta, no se si podria ayudarme

Comment: escríbeme: msolano2505@gmail.com y te ayudo....

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Answer (score -1):

No es nada recomendable ni normalizado guardar los archivos (imágenes, pdf, ...) como binarios en la BDD.

Cambia tu método de guardado mediante una copia de la imagen en un directorio accesible por la aplicación web y guarda en la base de datos la ruta a esa copia.

Lo lamento, mis conocimientos de PHP son básicos y por eso no te pongo como hacerlo, pero me parece importante dejarte indicada esta buena práctica.

Comment: Es mas un comentario que una respuesta. Aunque es excelente el aporte por buenas practicas de programación y estructuracion de la BD. @Miguel

Comment: Si, pero me faltan 2 puntos de reputación para poder comentar en su pregunta, por eso me he visto en la necesidad de escribir una respuesta.

Comment: Pues no Coincido con el comentario, si las imágenes a almacernar son documentos legales es muy mala práctica almacenar solo el directorio, varias veces son necesarias almacenar las imágenes en un campo blob. Así que las respuestas deberían de ser a lo que se pregunta y no confundirlo mas

Comment: Estás hablando de un caso extremadamente concreto, que con la seguridad y desarrollo adecuados para permitir el acceso al directorio únicamente a la aplicación sí es optimo. He trabajado con bases de datos que almacenaban una cantidad pequeña de documentos como blob y rápidamente han alcanzado los 40 Gb haciendo que sea muy dificilmente mantenible y migrable. Por otro lado, que se marque mi respuesta como no válida en vez de la otra como válida tampoco me parece correcto, puesto que he dado las nociones de lo que habría que hacer y la otra respuesta ha escrito en código lo que yo he propuesto.